# Regroup 2 level multiidex series to dataframe so that second level index becomes names?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

At first, generate simple dataframe and apply groupby and count nums.

```
import pandas as pd
import random

letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', ]
nums = [ str(n) for n in range(1, 6)]
combs = [
    [random.choice(letters), random.choice(nums)] for i in range(10)
]
    combs_df = pd.DataFrame(combs)
combs_df

""" 
    0   1
0   c   3
1   a   4
2   b   1
3   a   2
4   a   2
5   c   1
6   a   3
7   c   1
8   c   2
9   b   1
"""

s1 = combs_df.groupby([0, 1])[1].count()

type(s1)
# pandas.core.series.Series

s1.index
"""
MultiIndex(levels=[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['1', '2', '3', '4']],
           codes=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2]],
           names=[0, 1])
"""

s1

""" 

0  1<-----column 1
a  2    2
   3    1<-- count
   4    1    ...
b  1    2
c  1    2
   2    1
   3    1
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

I know how to implement this with python for loops.

## Is it possible with pandas from s1 series create a dataframe where 
column 1 from s1 becomes a head of a table, and count 
aggregation results  are placed in cells ? Like example below converted form s1:

```
"""
             1 2 3 4 <-- nums
letters--> a 0 2 1 1 
           b 2 0 0 0 <-- count
           c 2 1 1 0 
"""
```

Comment: `pd.crosstab(combs_df[0],combs_df[1])` or `combs_df.groupby([0, 1])[1].count().unstack()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s1 = s1.reset_index(name='count')
s2 = pd.pivot(s1, index=0, columns=1, values='count').fillna(0)
print(s2)
```

gives

```
1    1    2    3    4    5
0                         
a  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
b  1.0  2.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
c  2.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
```

Comment: You can replace NaNs with zeroes with `fillna(0)` to fully complete author's desirable result :)